# Can I set environment variables when configuring the Vite server?

Tags: vite

I have a custom plugin in Vite:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    {
      name: 'test-plugin',
      configureServer(server) {
        // import.meta.env.VITE_ENV_VAR = 'foo';
      }
    },
  ]
});
```

In the `configureServer` method, I'd like to be able to set an environment variable that I can reference later in a `.vue` file:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const var = import.meta.env.VITE_ENV_VAR;
</script>
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: The [`configureServer`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver) hook is called after the config is already resolved, but this can be done in the [`config`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#config) hook using [`define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define). See example [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envprefix). If that fully addresses your question, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what did I miss?

Comment: Appreciate the directional pointer. This managed to unblock me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`configureServer`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver) hook is called after the config is already [resolved](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-javascript.html#resolvedconfig), but this can be done in the [`config`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#config) hook using [`define`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define). An [example](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envprefix) is provided in the documentation:

> If you would like to expose an unprefixed variable, you can use [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) to expose it:
>
> ```js
> define: {
>   'import.meta.env.ENV_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV_VARIABLE)
> }
> ```